# Class.newInstance() oddity

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I'm working with two branches of a code base, where in the former a call to `classA.newInstance()` invokes classA's no-arg constructor, but in the latter the object is created without invoking classA's no-arg constructor, although the constructor exists in both, and I need it to be invoked because it does some trivial initialization.

Both versions of `classA` are nearly identical, minus a couple lines of code in an insignificant method and an additional import statement.  Its no-arg constructor doesn't throw exceptions and is publicly accessible in each version.  The calling class is also identical, except in the version that doesn't work it is in a slightly different package than it's other branch. I can't understand how it's ignoring the no-arg constructor. The class name is correct, access is the same, etc.

Am I missing something obvious? I'm stumped after researching online..maybe I'll start stepping through the `class.newInstance` code itself.  Hope this question makes sense!

Comment: I would bet that _the object is created without invoking classA's no-arg constructor_ must be false (or another constructor is called).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason eclipse just wasn't hitting my breakpoint.  It was invoking it,mbut internally it was pointed to the wrong fields in the class because of a bad import statement.  It's really crappy code.

Thanks for reading though, nerds!